# Minimal WordPress Functionality on Existing Website

Tags: theme-development

I have a client that wants the ability to remove or add a special offer from the front page of her website.

I thought of creating a custom loop using a featured image etc, which would display the latest special offer.

Her site is a PHP site right now without any WP functionality.

What is the minimum installation that would allow me to display this loop. Instead of creating a theme and template I just want to use the existing page.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you just used a sticky post? I've done this before and worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require the wp-load.php file in the existing page...

```
<?php require('wp-load.php') ?>
```

This will basically load the WordPress installation and allow you to access each of the functions (and the loop) as you normally would.

Comment: Phil, so do I load the rest of the WP files in the root directory?  And what would I do with the existing index.php file?  This is the page I need the functionality.  Just use my existing file and add this require?

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal WP install, attach a theme that consists of nothing than

- style.css
- functions.php
- index.php

Inside your index.php include everything from your current site. Then add the loop where you need it.